# path to file in class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class-library

I have a class libary project (NotificationTemplate) which return content of file:

```
public static class Template
{
    public static string NotificatioEmail
    {
        get { return File.ReadAllText("Templates\\NotificatioEmail.cshtml"); }
    }
}
```

In this project is located folder `Templates` with `NotificatioEmail.cshtml` file.

Also, I have two application: console app and ASP.NET MVC app. The file returned fine in the console app, but in the MVC I get error `file not found`. How to write universally?
I tryed this:

```
Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Templates",
             "NotificatioEmail.cshtml")
```

but `BaseDirectory` don't include `bin` folder.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As you said `BaseDirectory` works for console apps. For MVC applications, use [`RelativeSearchPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.relativesearchpath.aspx) instead.

So you can use this code for both platforms

```
var appDomain = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
var basePath = appDomain.RelativeSearchPath ?? appDomain.BaseDirectory;
Path.Combine(basePath, "Templates", "NotificatioEmail.cshtml");
```

Comment: This is works for asp.net, but not work in console applciation. It's  equal null.

Comment: @user348173 can you do `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath ?? System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` ?

Comment: That was a very useful solution for combining both web and console apps.

Comment: Make sure to set file property "Copy to Output Directory"  to "copy always" or "copy if never" , as per your requirement